# How to update this type of relationship table data in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, relationship

I have branch table one to one relationship with contact table and contact table has one to many relationship with phones,emails and Addresses table how I update this type of relationship in asp net core and entity freakwork

```
 public class Branch
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public BranchStatus status { get; set; }
    public Guid? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company? Company { get; set; }
    public Guid? ContactId { get; set; }
    public Contact? Contact { get; set; }     
  }

  public class Contact : IEntity<Guid>
   {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Address>? Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Phone>? Phones { get; set; }
    public List<Email>? Emails { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this up on the model classes using the `ForeignKey` attribute.